# Avoid recalculating some values with Enumerable methods

Tags: ruby, iteration, memoization

Some methods on `Enumerable` such as `max_by`, `min_by`, or `find` evaluate some related value for the items iterated, and give back one of the original items. I often want not the original value but the evaluated form. In this example:

```
max = some_enumerable_object.max_by{|e| some_function(e)}
some_function(max)
```

`max_by` selects an item `max`, but I want the value `some_function(max)` rather than the `max` itself. Doing `some_function(max)` seems waste of calculation because it was already evaluated within the iteration. Is there a way to access `some_function(max)` without recalculation?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `map` then `max`:

```
max_value = some_enumerable_object.map { |e| some_function(e) }.max
```

Comment: With `max` and `min`, that is okay, but with `find`, that requires a bit of an extra calculation because `map` will calculate `some_function(e)` for all elements whereas `find` will cut off the calculation once the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `map` to create a sub-array containing your original value, along with your computed value:

```
max = some_enumerable_object.map{ |o|
  [o, some_function(o)] 
}.max_by{ |o,e| e }
```

Once you're done, you can grab your original value, or the result of the function in your `max` variable.

Comment: The same comment applies to your answer as rossta's.

Comment: Of course it will, but I was working from the need to not rerun the calculation. Baby steps... baby steps.